# Как дублировать содержание select в соседнюю строку?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо при выборе значение в выпадающим списке чтобы он это значение тут же передал в span. При вводе информации через текстовое поле у меня получилось это сделать используя следующий JS код выводя значение по ID span (пример `<span id="title-place">)</span>`)
Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
var get_title = $("#listing_title");
    var view_title = $("#property-title-fill");
    var selected = null;

    function keyup_fill(ele, ele_place) {
        $(ele).on("keyup", function(event) {
            if ($(ele).attr("name") === "night_price") {
                if (!$.isNumeric($(ele).val())) {
                    return
                }
            }

            if ($(ele).attr("name") === "listing_bedrooms" || $(ele).attr("name") === "guests" || $(ele).attr("name") === "baths") {
                if (!$.isNumeric($(ele).val())) {
                    return
                }
            }



            var newText = event.target.value;
            $(ele_place).html(newText); 
        });
    }

    keyup_fill("#listing_title", "#title-place");
    keyup_fill("#listing_address", "#address-place");
    keyup_fill("#night_price", "#price-place");
    keyup_fill("#hour_price", "#price-place");
    keyup_fill("#listing_bedrooms", "#total-beds");
    keyup_fill("#guests", "#total-guests");
    keyup_fill("#baths", "#total-baths");



    function amenities_selector(ele, view_ele, is_text) {
        $(ele).on('change', function() {
            if(is_text == 'yes') {
                var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
            } else {
                var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
            }
            $(view_ele).html(selected);
        });
    }
    amenities_selector("#listing_type", "#listing-type-view", 'yes');
```

Comment: Используйте событие on( 'input',... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#testSelect").change(function(e) {
  $("#title-place").text($(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).text());
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="testSelect">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<span id="title-place">Empty</span>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Я мало знаком с JS, не получается правильно вставить код. Подскажите, в какую часть представленного кода необходимо вставить ваш код?

Comment: @Дмитрий Вставьте в самом конце - после всего.